# How to install flash for windows application with crossover or wine?

Tags: flash, crossplatform, crossover

I am currently using crossover to run windows application. It is a flash application compiled to .exe. I ran the application and it shows,

> "Failed to Load flash player"

How do I fix that problem? I am quite sure that you guys have this problem too.

If you need more information, please ask below.

If you do not understand, you might want to see a screenshot of the problem, or just comment to ask further question.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwOwf.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way, is to download windows's version of flash player, and install it on wine or cross-over. Re-run the application, it should work.